# Cannot add property X, object is not extensible after ngrx 9 update

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, angular9

I am having an issue like

> Cannot add property X, object is not extensible

after updating my angular project to angular 9 with Ngrx update as well. When I rollback Ngrxversion to 8 it's working fine. But I need to update that as well to v9 with angular 9 updates. This has happened when I add this as datasource.data in the material table with additional attribute. I think that additional attribute alteration is a reason for that. But I create new array from what we got and tried out like below by using slice.

```
 myDataArray.slice(0)
```

It also not working.

I refer change list of Ngrx version 8 to 9 and migration guideline here https://ngrx.io/guide/migration/v9

As I found there is a special change related to immutability with angular 9. They have defined Action, state and serializability related immutability logic there. And I tried out the method that they have suggested to resolve those issues with Ngrx V9 update here https://ngrx.io/guide/store/configuration/runtime-checks

But those are not worked for me. It's really helpful if anyone has a solution to this issue. Thanks in advance..

error stack trace.. (I used matDataFlatner as well that's where the object mutation happens)

> app-error-handler.ts:30 TypeError: Cannot add property level, object
>   is not extensible
>       at MatTreeFlattener.defaultFlattenerTransform [as transformFunction] (tree-table-flattener-builder.ts:57)
>       at MatTreeFlattener._flattenNode (flat-data-source.ts:58)
>       at flat-data-source.ts:81
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at MatTreeFlattener._flattenChildren (flat-data-source.ts:78)
>       at MatTreeFlattener._flattenNode (flat-data-source.ts:65)
>       at flat-data-source.ts:92
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at MatTreeFlattener.flattenNodes (flat-data-source.ts:92)
>       at MatTreeFlatDataSource.set (flat-data-source.ts:138)

Comment: Have you tried cloning the object that comes from the store? Supposing myDataArray is coming from the store through a selector, try doing `myDataArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myDataArray))`, or any other method for deep cloning.

Comment: It would help if you post the actual error with stack trace. That gives a better idea which action is causing this

Comment: @PierreDuc I added stack trace. Can u have a look

Comment: @julianobrasil Thanks a lot. That is working. Is there any reason for that.? Is there any other good mechanism for deep cloning...

Comment: Well, in a perfect world, you should try to solve the issue using one of the techniques on the link you've posted related to runtime-checks. Anyway, if you really need to stick to deep cloning you could try https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-copy

Comment: @julianobrasil Thanks a lot for ur support. U can add ur solution as an answer I can approve it

Comment: Thanks! I'll do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot add property "X", object is not extensible angular 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60631071/cannot-add-property-x-object-is-not-extensible-angular-9)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You should deep-clone `myDataArray` because it's coming out from the store through a selector. Keeping the immutability of the data in the store is an important part of redux pattern and you'd be changing the data directly in the store if you modify `myDataArray` (depending on your selector, it could be the same data => a reference to the array in the store).

You can do `myDataArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myDataArray))` before trying to make any change in it.

There are more efficient ways of deep-cloning an object, for example using [fast-copy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-copy):

```js
import copy from 'fast-copy';

...

myDataArray = copy(myDataArray);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use cloneDeep function from lodash library to deep clone the object and avoid the error:

`import {cloneDeep} from 'lodash';`

`const clonedData = cloneDeep(myDataArray);`

Then, you can add properties or all that you want to clonedData object.

Regards!

Answer (score 6):

I refer change list of Ngrx version 8 to 9 and migration guideline here

https://ngrx.io/guide/migration/v9

As I found there is a special change related to immutability with angular 9. They have defined Action, state and serializability related immutability logic there. And I tried out the method that they have suggested to resolve those issues with Ngrx V9 update here

https://ngrx.io/guide/store/configuration/runtime-checks

You can make following change,

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
  StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, {
    runtimeChecks: {
      strictStateImmutability: false,
      strictActionImmutability: false,
    },
  }),
 ],
})
export class AppModule {}

@ngrx/store ships with five (5) built-in runtime checks. Try disabled all checks
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved my issue after updating an ngrx (from 6 to 9) in an old project, that then broke MomentJS's ability to parse from a string: `"Cannot add property _weekdaysShortRegex, object is not extensible"`. Safe to say, MomentJS will be prioritized for replacement in this project.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue we need to clone the data of selectors (`createSelector`)

Example:
Earlier before the upgrade of Ngrx or Angular your code looks like this:

```
export const getFrameworkCitationsSuccess = createSelector(getFrameworkState, (state: FrameworkState) => {
  return { frameworkCitations: state.frameworkCitations, filters: state.filters };
});
```

After upgrade of Ngrx or Angular do the following changes:

```
export const getFrameworkCitationsSuccess = createSelector(getFrameworkState, (state: FrameworkState) => {
  return { frameworkCitations: [...state.frameworkCitations], filters: {...state.filters} };
});
```

SS:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you need to keep the data in store immutable you need to do a deep clone(as other answers also refer).
Another way to do a deep clone of an object is to work with `structuredClone` method.
For instance:

`newLoadList = structuredClone(state.loadsList);`

Now `newLoadList` is a deep copy of the state's property `loadsList`.

So, inside a reducer you could work with the newLoadsList to add, update etc and then return it in the state.