# TypeError: Cannot add property 0, object is not extensible after implement NGXS

Tags: angular, ngxs

My application is a to-do list - you can creating new tasks (tasks are grouped within sprints);
It also allows you to assign a person to a task and the time it will take for that person to complete it.

I am trying to implement ngxs in my application - my app worked fine until I added this line in createTask method:

```
this.store.dispatch(new AddTask(task));
```

when I add that line, adding people to task (method: changePersonAssigneInTask) stops working and I get this error in the browser console:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot add property 0, object is not extensible
    at Array.push (<anonymous>)
    at DataBaseService.addPersonToTask (data-base.service.ts:78:20)
    at DataBaseService.changePersonAssigneInTask (data-base.service.ts:63:16)
    at DataService.changePersonAssigneInTask (data.service.ts:37:26)
    at TaskComponent.changePersonAssigneInTask (task.component.ts:68:22)
    at TaskComponent_div_20_Template_button_click_9_listener (task.component.html:49:28)
    at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (core.mjs:14979:1)
    at wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault (core.mjs:15017:1)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.mjs:466:38)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:406:1)
```

The structure of my project is as follows:

```
export interface Sprint {
  personCapacities: PersonCapacity[];
  tasks: Task[];
  dates: Dates[];
  name: string;
}

export interface Task {
  number: string;
  name: string;
  assignees: Assignee[];

}

export interface Assignee {
  person: Person;
  hours: number;
}
```

CREATING TASKS:

```
  createTask() {

    const task: Task = {
      number: this.taskNumber,
      name: this.taskName,
      assignees: []
    };

    this.dataService.addTask(task, this.chosenSprint);
    this.store.dispatch(new AddTask(task));

  }
```

and addTask method in dataService:

```
     addTask(task: Task, chosenSprint: Sprint)
      {
          this.sprints.find(value =>
            {
             if(value.name==chosenSprint.name)
              value.tasks.push(task)
            }
          )
      }
```

ASSIGNING A PERSON WITH HOURS TO A TASK:

```
  changePersonAssigneInTask(person: Person, hours: number, task: Task) {
    this.dataService.changePersonAssigneInTask(person, hours, task);
  }
```

and changePersonAssigneInTask in dataService:

```
  changePersonAssigneInTask(person: Person, hours: number, task: Task)
  {
      let assignee = task.assignees.find(p => p.person.shortName == person.shortName);
      if ( assignee == null) {
          this.addPersonToTask(person, hours, task);
      } else {
          this.updatePersonHoursInTask(person, hours, task, assignee);
      }
  }
```

and addPersonToTask in dataService:

```
addPersonToTask(person: Person, hours: number, task: Task){


    task.assignees.push({ //<--error generating in this line
      person,
      hours
    });
  }
```

My actions.ts file:

```
import {Task} from "../../models/task";

export class AddTask{
  static readonly type = '[TASK] Add Task';
  constructor(public task: Task) {
  }
}
```

My state.ts file:

```
import {Action, Selector, State, StateContext} from '@ngxs/store';
import {AddTask} from '../actions/actions';
import {Task} from "../../models/task";
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Role} from "../../models/person";

export interface TaskInterface {
  tasks: Task[];
}

@State<TaskInterface>({
  name: 't',
  defaults: {
    tasks: []
  }
})

@Injectable()
export class AddTaskAction{

  @Action(AddTask)
  AddTask(ctx: StateContext<TaskInterface>, action: AddTask){

    const {task} = action;
    const state = ctx.getState();

    if(!task)
      return;


    ctx.setState({
      ...state,
      tasks: [...state.tasks, task]
      });

    console.log(ctx.getState());
}

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot add property X, object is not extensible after ngrx 9 update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60882954/cannot-add-property-x-object-is-not-extensible-after-ngrx-9-update)

Comment: not really ... when I use this method:
`code`
var task_copy = copy(task);
    task_copy.assignees.push({
      person,
      hours
    });
`code`
i have no bug in console but i can't see newly assigned person to task on gui like it used to be